# How to execute Ruby Script from LAMP Web Application

Tags: ruby, lamp

I have installed rvm (mutiuser option) and ruby using "rvm install" on my test server running Ubuntu.
If I log in and execute "ruby test.rb", the script runs correctly.
But If I execute it using "exec" from my php code, I get an error.

If I "su www-data" and try to execute the script then I get the same error, so I guess the question is how to get "www-data" to have the correct environment to execute Ruby scripts. I've already tried adding "www-data" to "rvm" group and doesn't work. If I give the full path to Ruby bin, then the script executes, but fails when requiring gems.

I've also tried executing a .sh where the fist line is "rvm use ruby-xxx" and the second line is "ruby test.rb" and doesn't work either.

Should I install Ruby using "apt-get install"?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I don't know about multi-user version, but if you were running a single user version, you could run scripts as that user, like this:

```
/bin/su - postgres -c "/path/to/backup_db.sh /tmp/test"
```

See [this question and answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/44400/run-a-shell-script-as-a-different-user).

Comment: So you're saying I should undo what I did, install rvm and ruby for a normal user, and then "su" to that user? I'm going to try it. I'd like to know how to configure it with www-data anyway.

Comment: @martincho: I'm not saying you should, but you *could* :-)